# How to check if two branches changed the same line (automatically)

Tags: git, git-merge

Imagine that we created two branches from `master`, `branch1`, and `branch2`.

How could we detect using `git` that `branch1` and `branch2` changed the same line?

We do not care about intermediate commits in the new branches. We just need to check the difference between `branch1` and `master` and the differences between `branch2` and `master` and check if they changed any common line.

Thanks in advance.

Ps: we cannot cherry-pick all the commits in the branches in order to detect possible conflicts, this approach would produce false positives.

Comment: Do both `branch1` and `branch2` have latest code from `master` branch? Or rather, do they have the same commits from `master`?

Comment: We could assume as a first approach that both branches have the same commits from `master`. Anyway it would be awesome not to depend on this assumption.

Comment: Is the question whether merging branch1 and branch2 into master would cause a merge conflict?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to view the diffs, you can compare :

```
git diff master...branch1    # three dots
```

and

```
git diff master...branch2
```

---

Say `branch1` (resp. `branch2`) forked from `master` at commit `c1` (resp. `c2`).

You could try to apply the changes brought by `branch1` on top of `c2`, and see how this compares with the content of `branch2`.

Here is one way to do that :

```
# create a temporary branch 'tmp1' starting at the same commit as branch1
git checkout -b tmp1 branch1

# squash all history to one single commit
git reset --soft c1
git commit -m "branch1 content"

# replay that commit on top of c2 :
git checkout -b tmp2 c2
git cherry-pick tmp1

# you can now compare tmp2 and branch2 :
git diff tmp2 branch2
```

Comment: Thanks LeGEC, how could I compare these outputs automatically in order to detect the same change?